# Trigger php file to run

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get couple of data from a mysql db.

1. How do I just trigger a php from a javascript file?
2. How do I fetch the results back from the javascript file?

Comment: Would you like to use the jquery. It is a javascript framework.

Comment: I have posted a script in javascript.It will also help you.

Comment: Do you need the jquery script? @NathaliaZeed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the script for your requirement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showInformation()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
    mlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
  //this is the result you can get here.
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","xxx.php",true); 
 //xxx.php is the php file you want to fetch data from
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```

Thanks

Here is the jquery script to do the same operation:

```
function getInformation(){
$.post('xxx.php',{'param':'..value..'},function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
}
```

Note: before this include the jquery.js file in your script.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use **Ajax** to get data from mysql db.

Tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/